# R package install Jupyter notebook

Tags: r, install.packages

Trying to install R library - MAC - Jupyter notebook
using:

```
install.packages("TSA")

also installing the dependency ‘locfit’

Warning message in install.packages("TSA"):
“installation of package ‘locfit’ had non-zero exit status”Warning message in install.packages("TSA"):
“installation of package ‘TSA’ had non-zero exit status”Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done

library(TSA)

Error in library(TSA): there is no package called ‘TSA’
Traceback:

1. library(TSA)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that your version of R (not RStudio) is greater than 3.5?  If not, try to update it.  With a Mac, this code should work:
install.packages('devtools') #assuming it is not already installed
library(devtools)
install_github('andreacirilloac/updateR')
library(updateR)
updateR(admin_password = 'Admin user password')